# xelatex memory problem

Tags: macros, xetex, errors, memory

I have problem while running **xelatex**:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=1500000].
```

I tried increasing memory limits in **texmf.cnf** (also ran **fmtutil-sys**), but I hit maximum allowed and it still crashes with same error (just different memory amount).

There are no other warnings or errors than one mentioned above (when it crashes).

I use packages: *babel*, *fontenc*, *inputenc*, *graphicx*, *ifthen*, *multicol*, *fontspec*, *xunicode*, *xltxtra* and *xcolor*.

I use true type font:

```
\setmainfont{LiberationSansNarrow}
```

Document is started and ended with commands:

```
\newcommand{\stardoc}[0]
{
  \begin{multicols}{4}
}


\newcommand{\donedoc}[0]
{
 \end{multicols}
}
```

(Just wrappers (put in custom class so there can be changed for many documents).

Between multi-columns I include (with *\include*) "large" file (~3MB) consisting of following commands:

```
\newcommand{\myrow}[4]
{
 \noindent
 \vbox to 15pt {\vfil
    \hbox to \columnwidth {
      \parbox{0.97\columnwidth}{
        \tiny
        \textbf{#1}\dotfill#3\\
        \emph{#2}\hfill{#4}}%\vspace{6pt}
      }
      \vfil
     }
 }

\newcommand{\myblock}[1]
{
 \noindent
 \colorbox{gray}{
    \vbox to 15pt {\vfil
      \hbox to 0.913\columnwidth {
        \hfill\textbf{{\small #1}}\hfill
      }
      \vfil
    }
  }
}
```

Here is also end of **.log** file:

```
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 6293 strings out of 191470
 96261 string characters out of 1925444
 1500000 words of memory out of 1500000
 9402 multiletter control sequences out of 10000+200000
 6692 words of font info for 33 fonts, out of 1200000 for 2000
 605 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 35i,5n,37p,320b,232s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,6000p,200000b,15000s
No pages of output.
```

If I cut input file to ~30% (~1MB) then everything goes OK and pdf is produced.

I assume there is an error somewhere in custom defined commands as I am not an expert - please help me.

**EDIT**

Per request in comments, input file is just a series of *\myrow* and *\myblock* commands generated from the database.

It works if I add *\par* before *\noindent* in any of the commands, but that creates spacings... Is there a way to make *\par* produce no extra spacings - my layout prior adding *\par* command was perfect.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! My suspect is that you're trying to make XeTeX swallow the entire file before making a paragraph. But the information you give is too scarce for making a diagnosis. What's in the file you're inputting?

Comment: Try if it works if you add a `\par` before \noindent in your commands. If this doesn't help, you will have to make more code accessible.

Comment: Input file is auto generated listing from database consisting only of: _\myrow{text1}{text2}{text3}{text4}_ and _\myblock{text}_ commands. Text of arguments to those commands is never longer than 50 characters and every command is in it's own line (but that shouldn't matter).

Comment: It works if I add \par, but it adds much space between boxes and rows and it also creates bunch of _Underfull \hbox_ warnings. Why does this work, what is the magic? :)

Comment: TeX always read a complete paragraph in its memory. If the whole text is one large paragraph this will overburden the memory. You will have to adapt your commands so that they use `\par` at sensible places.

Comment: your text (without the intermediate `\par`) is just a single paragraph.  it would seem that tex can't find a point to break your huge file up into pages.  so it tries to fit your 3mbyte file into its 1.5mbyte main memory, and fails.  inserted `\par` tokens give it a break point, so it can form your text into pages, and flush those pages out.  a small working document would be good: we could get a feel of what it's like; we definitely don't want you multiple megabutes, just a few rows in as the "rest" of the doc.

Comment: I edited the post with relevant information you asked - now I only need a way to make _\par_ command produce no extra spacing (or to make it flush pages out in some other manner)

Comment: @IvanR -- It is really hard to say what you are doing since you need to post a *real* and compilable (and minimal) example of the document you have.  One thing that sticks out is that your macro definitions seem to introduce a fair amount of spurious space at the start and end of some commands.  You are also changing the fontsize with `\tiny` and `\small` while using `\vbox`-es and `\vfil`-s while all still in the same paragraph.  That might do some funky stuff, too.  However, I bet someone can fix your problem if you give an example that starts `\documentclass` and ends `\end{document}`.

Comment: @jon But there isn't anything else :) I define my own class with mentioned packages and inside I define 4 commands mentioned above. Main file is just _\begin{document}_ [generated data] _\end{document}_ - That's it.

Comment: Good news is that I found a solution - I simply added extra newline at end of the _\myrow_ command and everything works as before but it doesn't break. (I cannon mark answer correct as everyone just commented, but you helped, so thnx :))

Answer (score 0):

So, solution is found - thnx to people in the comments.

Problem with memory was, as stated, that I was trying to chew too much in one paragraph so it broke. First i tried inserting *\pre* prior to *\noindent*, but that create the problem of too much spaces between boxes and rows.

That problem was solved by inserting newline at the end of *\myrow* command, so it looks something like this:

```
\newcommand{\myrow}[4]
{
 \noindent
 \vbox to 15pt {\vfil
    \hbox to \columnwidth {
      \parbox{0.97\columnwidth}{
        \tiny
        \textbf{#1}\dotfill#3\\
        \emph{#2}\hfill{#4}}%\vspace{6pt}
      }
      \vfil
     }

 }
```

This creates paragraphs (or something that allows creation of pages before everything is processed in memory), but also doesn't create spaces between boxes and rows.

Thnx everyone