# Typesetting problem (XeTeX)

Tags: errors

```
Capitolo 2.
./Preambolo consigliato.tex:660: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [semantic nest size=500].
<recently read> {

l.660 \jg
     &j\\
```

an error I've just gotten out of typesetting the gist at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8235799. Can I fix that? And how?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What _do_ you think the gist is for? If you remove every chapter but the last one the error is still produced. In case you want a shorter code. In fact it appears that matrix at the end _is_ the problem. So if you take the gist and remove all chapters but the last one and leave that chapter with just the matrix, it should give the same problem. Too many lines in that matrix, maybe? If I remove the lines from `\jg&j` on the problem vanishes, but inserting another matrix gets the problem back.

Comment: @MickG The reason for asking for a MWE here is that we've no idea where `\jg` might come from. Without seeing the preamble, _etc._ it's not at all obvious.

Comment: Look at the gist! And anyway the problem is solved right below.

Comment: The keyword is *minimal*, the gist is in no way minimal. As you say yourself, nearly all of the content can be removed from the document, and I'd guess you can remove most of the preamble as well. Also, it's preferred that questions are self-contained, not relying on external sites.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem caused by an error of the questioner.

Comment: Well the question is about a typesetting error so I wouldn't call it off-topic. It _is_ true that it was caused by my mistake, ad as I know that it can be closed as solved. An analogous question was http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74046/xelatex-memory-problem?rq=1. If someone bumps into this question, it might help them find an error similar to mine and correct it. Else, they can try seeing that other question. This is all.

Comment: @MickG -- you suggest that seeing this question might help someone else.  all the more reason for a minimal example.  "outside" examples may disappear, at which time whatever is left here is probably useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: command calling itself in its definition. Basically, a b got left in the keyboard when defining:

```
\newcommand{\jg}{\tallsc{\bjg}}
```

As a result, `\jg` calls itself, and LaTeX complains. Put the b in place, and the error goes away.